# Plotting categorical data along with numerical variable

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, data-visualization, dataset, interactive-visualization

I have data like as shown below

[image]

I would like to represent the above tabular data in a visual form.

However, the below graph may not work because my real data as 50K unique drug names. Doing so, will make the x-axis messy. Is there any other condensed way to represent this?

[image]

So, is there any better way to represent this? Can you share some suggestions on how this can be represented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would you like to communicate with the plot?

For a summary of the dataset, you can think about a scatter plot with x = unique no patients, y = no of units prescribed and put a label close to each point representing the drug id.
This is an example with the dataset `mtcars`

```
library("ggplot2")
data("mtcars")

mtcars$mdl <- rownames(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, label=mdl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(check_overlap=TRUE, vjust="inward", hjust="inward")
```

[image]

Set `check_overlap=FALSE` if you want to see all (overlapping) labels.

Since you have a large number of points, you may want to label just those that can be informative about how the data is distributed.
To do that, you can do a scatter plot

```
plot(x=mtcars$mpg, y=mtcars$wt)
```

then use `identify` to click on the points you want to label

```
identify(x=mtcars$mpg, y=mtcars$wt, labels=mtcars$mdl, cex=0.8)
```

You have to click on the points that you want to label, then press `ESC`.

If you want to do it programmatically, you can set all labels to `NA` except those that you want to show:

```
mtcars$mdl_1 <- mtcars$mdl
mtcars$mdl_1[-sample(nrow(mtcars), 5)] <- NA  # Select 5 random to keep

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, label=mdl_1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(check_overlap=FALSE,vjust="inward",hjust="inward")
```

## More than 2 variables:

In this case, you can use `pairs` or `ggpairs` from `GGally` package

```
library(GGally)

mtcars$mdl <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$mdl_1 <- mtcars$mdl
mtcars$mdl_1[-sample(nrow(mtcars), 5)] <- NA  ## Showing 5 random labels

gg <- ggpairs(data=mtcars, columns=c(1:5), aes(label=mdl_1))
for (i in 1:25) {  ## 5*5 plots
  for (j in 1:25) {
    if (j < i) {  ## lower half
      plt <- getPlot(gg,i,j) + geom_text(size=3) + geom_point(size=1)
      gg <- putPlot(gg,plt,i,j)
    }
  }
}

gg
```

[image]

where I've customized the scatter plots using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882326/13584139).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. good to know this approach. But Is there anyway to hide names as well? Because I think my drug names might be lengthy. Instead if I would like to show just as cluster points without names, is it possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a method to label only the points chosen by you. This is done interactively. If you set the labels to `NA`, they won't be shown.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. In addition, I actually have another 3-dimensional axis problem. can help me with that as well?

Comment: I'm gonna update the answer for such case.

Comment: May I know how do we set the axis interval instead of the code automatically picking up one? `mtcars$mdl <- rownames(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, label=mdl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(check_overlap=TRUE, vjust="inward", hjust="inward")`

Comment: `scale_x_continuous`, `scale_y_continuous` (or `discrete`) allow you to do that, by setting the param `limits`:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.3.2/topics/scale_continuous

like: `ggplot(...) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1))` will plot the data with `x >= 0 & x <= 1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110272/discussion-between-the-great-and-ping).